# Applying a view link

Tags: php

I am using the following Code, to get data from the Database in phpmyadmin, and showing it in a html table. In the message column i have put a view link, to show the complete message when clicked. I have truncated the message successfully. Now that the View Link's onclick event is not working. Please see if i am doing sth wrong.:

```
    <?php $i=0;?>
   <table border="1" style="position:absolute; left: 197px; top: 50px;">
   <tr>
  <td width="236" style="font-family:Ravie; color:#313253; text-align:center">Name</td>
  <td width="225" style="font-family:Ravie; color:#313253; text-align:center">
   Email Address</td>
  <td width="267" style="font-family:Ravie; color:#313253; 
  text-align:center">Message</td>
  </tr>
  <?php
  $i=0;
  while ($i < $num) {

  $f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"FullName");
  $f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"EmailAddr");
  $string=mysql_result($result,$i,"Message");
  $limit=10;
  $string1 = myTruncate($string,$limit);

  ?>

  <tr>
  <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font></td>
  <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f2; ?></font></td>
  <td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $string1; ?></font>
  <a href="" onclick="<?php echo $string; ?>">View</a></td>

   </tr>

   <?php
   $i++;
   }
  ?>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onclick` requires Javascript code, you can't just enter raw content and expect it to show after a click. Do you want to use an `alert()` messagebox to show the message? If so, try:

```
<a href="" onclick="alert('<?php echo $string; ?>');">View</a>
```

If you're `$string` has any quotes in it you'll need to escape them.

I suggest adding the onclick event handler separately, for example on page load, rather than inline.